# Image causing horizontal scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the tympanus Sedna freebie template as a base for a page and added a few plugins etc here

http://www.onlineallies.co.uk/pages/Sedna/index.html

One of these changes/additions has caused this image

http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Sedna/img/macbook-pro.png

to extend beyond the body and cause horizontal scrolling. I've searched other horiz scroll posts on here but no solutions have worked.

Any ideas as to what is causing or overriding the original templates css.

Thanks for reading

Comment: you probably will have to use media queries to reduce the width of the image. Start with the image width of 825px.

Comment: you can add (zoom: .7;) to (.features-extra .macbook-wrap) in the css. this will fix the issue with chrome & safari. you can try (transform:scale) for all others but you may need a container around the image -- http://s9.postimg.org/rtcnhxkof/Capture.jpg

Comment: Thank you I understand what you mean however the original template doesn't have this issue and I haven't purposefully made any changes to that part of the code so trying to understand why the behaviour is different. http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Sedna/ link to original site without Hz Scrolling

Answer (score 1):

I looked at both sites and the images look alike.

If you resize the view-port then yes, the image overflows to the right and the scroll bar appears.

Seems to me it was designed that way.

Try the site in a bigger resolution screen or in full screen mode [F11]. ;)

Looking closer you modified your body tag adding

```
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

Doing this disrupted the overflow for the rest of the page on the x axis. 
Just add to the body tag:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

It fixed your issue on my end.

Comment: Thank you but the original template doesn't have this issue, please see here http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Sedna/

Comment: I updated the answer, just specify the overflow for the x axis on the body tag.